# Python error when tryint to access list by index - “List indices must be integers, not str”

Tags: python, gammu

I have this Python code:

```
sm.GetSMSStatus() 
sm.GetSMSFolders() 
sms = sm.GetNextSMS(Start = True, Folder=0)
sms = sm.GetNextSMS(Location = sms['Location'], Folder=0)
sms = sm.GetSMS(Location = loc, Folder = 0)
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sms_teste.py", line 43, in <module>
    sms = sm.GetNextSMS(Location = sms['Location'], Folder=0)
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What I did to try to solve:

First I've been looking for answers to identical problems, however I can not find any that is similar.

According made ​​a print of sms variable to see what it returns and see how is allocated 'Location', and this is the print on:

```
[{'RejectDuplicates': 0, 'SMSCDateTime': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 1, 16, 31, 58), 'Class': 1, 'Name': u'', 'InboxFolder': 0, 'Text': u'dsgfzggzdfrg', 'SMSC': {'DefaultNumber': u'', 'Format': 'Text', 'Number': u'+#####', 'Validity': 'Max', 'Location': 0, 'Name': u''}, 'ReplaceMessage': 0, 'Coding': 'Default_No_Compression', 'Number': u'+#####', 'DateTime': None, 'DeliveryStatus': 0, 'State': 'UnSent', 'MessageReference': 0, 'Length': 12, 'Location': 0, 'Memory': 'SM', 'ReplyViaSameSMSC': 0, 'UDH': {'Text': '', 'ID16bit': 0, 'AllParts': 0, 'ID8bit': 0, 'PartNumber': -1, 'Type': 'NoUDH'}, 'Type': 'Submit', 'Folder': 2}]
```

and I noticed that 'Location' is equal to 0, but your key to getting there is 'Location'
But now I'm in a dead end, how do I transform a key string to integer when the variable itself is made ​​with string keys?
I am using gammu, so the form are returned as the result of functions is pre-formatted.

Someone can give me a hand?

I hope my information will be useful so that you can understand my question
P. S. the phone numbers are on # # # on purpose

Comment: so `sms` is a list *containing* one dictionary, not one dictionary. `sms['Location]'` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that `sms` is a *list* (because of the brackets `[]`). And its only element is a dictionary `{}`.

**What can you do?** You can access to the unique element of that list, which will be a dictionary:

```
sms[0]['Location']
......
   '-----> dictionary
```

Comment: ah ok! then whenever you want to access a list element is as if acting in json?
Thank you for helping

Comment: This has nothing to do with json, using `some_list[index]` is the syntax to access to an element in a specific index of a list/tuple.

Comment: I know, this is python, json spoke of the way that we can access parts of arrays passed by json :)

Answer (score 0):

`sms` is a `list`, which will not accept indices of type `str`:

```
>>> type(sms)
<type 'list'>
```

And it contains a dictionary:

```
>>> type(sms[0])
<type 'dict'>
```

Thus, you can issue:

```
>>> sms[0]['Location']
0
```